# using Search Server 2010 Express web service results are returning .aspx pages instead of documents

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint-2010

I have a Search web reference (from a Search Server 2010 express install) in a vb.net application that is utilizing the QueryService Class to search a production Sharepoint foundation 2010 site.

At a previous point in time, we had created a proof of concept on an entirely test system that has since been turfed.  From my recollection on this test system when documents were uploaded as a specific site content type (that inherits from document) and metadata was provided, we could search for specific metadata by making managed properties for each, and search results would be returned as documents (with the isdocument flag set to true).  Viewing the document then became simple, as we could simply use the filename and path to display the stored file.

Now we are developing a production system and we have encountered a new behavior, where these results now are returned as aspx results such as

```
http://digitizaton/Company/Client Documents/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=1703
```

This of course makes it terribly difficult to locate and view the document, we can extract the Title which will then give us the name of the file with no extension, but that hardly helps, as the FileExtension data is aspx, not the documents file extension, so we don't have a full filename.  We could display the page returned as a result, but would much prefer the document itself.

I've made a test document library, with just bare bones setup, (not using the site content type, or site columns) and uploaded some documents on the same site, and they are returned in the same fashion, so I don't believe the document library, or content type are the issue.

With a fairly limited understanding of both Sharepoint and Search Server, I don't know if this is a setup issue with the search service itself, with the site configuration, or with the querypacket I am sending.  We also have a third party application (Knowledgelake) installed on the server that ties into sharepoint which could have changed configuration somewhere as well?

I don't think the query packet has changed since it was working in the proof of concept, other than the custom data column names.  I will provide it here in case there is something glaringly obvious to an external reader.

```
<QueryPacket xmlns='urn:Microsoft.Search.Query.Document'>"
  <Query>
    <SupportedFormats>
        <Format>urn:Microsoft.Search.Response</Format>
    </SupportedFormats>
    <Range>
     <Count>0</Count>
    </Range>
   <Context>
      <QueryText type='MSSQLFT'>
       SELECT Filename, Title, FileExtension, IsDocument, Path from Scope() WHERE ""Scope"" = 'Department1' AND CustomData = 'X' -- 
      </QueryText>
    </Context>
```

Any guidance would be incredibly appreciated.  If I have not provided some relevant information, please let me know and I can track it down.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So now I feel like an idiot, I've searched for hours with no luck, and literally seconds after composing this post, I find the nugget of gold I've been searching for.

It appears that our primary file type, PDF, has a known issue with Sharepoint 2010, as shown at the following site.

http://www.sharepointsharon.com/2010/03/sharepoint-2010-and-adobe-pdf/

and further to that, this registry entry setting is required to link it all together

http://www.mossgurus.com/adnan/Lists/Categories/Category.aspx?Name=SharePoint%202010%20--%20Configuration